# Can I used Redis as SignalR Backplane for Server Side Blazor application?

Tags: redis, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm planning to buid a Server Side Blazor application.

It will be containerized with Docker and deployed to Amazon AWS, so in order to handle the scale-out for the service I don't have the option to use Azure SignalR service as Microsoft recommends in their documentation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#signalr-configuration).

We are curently using Redis as a backplane to manage our SignalR connections for another service, and I was wondering if it is possible to also use it in the same way for the Server Side Blazor application (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

What do you think?

Thanks,
Xavi

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: [Using Redis as a backplane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-7.0)